# Perl ODBC SSL connection to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, perl, odbc

I use the following to connect an application (client on Windows) to a remote MSSQL database:

```
use DBD::ODBC;
$dbh = DBI->connect(
   "dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};
    Server=$SQLservice;UID=$SQLuser;PWD=$SQLpassword", 
    {PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => $AutoCommit, FetchHashKeyName => 'NAME_lc'}
) or die "Can't connect to the database: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

Now my company asks if it is possible for the clients to use SQL Server 2017 with SSL. DBD::ODBC doesn't mention SSL at all, and I have not found any information on the internet (not to say details instrctions on how to realize it). Does it mean, I should answer "no"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best solution for your case will be to force encrypted connection on the SQL Server itself. To do this on the server open SQL Server Configuration Manager, in SQL Server Network Configuration right click Protocols for your server and click Properties. On the Certificate tab, select the desired certificate from the drop-down for the Certificate box, and on the Flags tab, in the Force Encryption box, select Yes. Restart the SQL Server service.

[image]

Of course, in this case you will need to setup certificates. For detailed information you can see Microsoft's article [Enable Encrypted Connections to the Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Thank you Andrey. And on the client side? Nothing to do here? It seems to nice to be true...

Comment: Yeah, that's why the option is called "Force" encryption :) On the client, you may have to do something to make the certificate trusted, but in general no changes in the connection string are necessary.

Comment: Interesting. With DBD::mysql you have to set it explicitly (pointing to certificates, etc.)